# FRP with Bacon.js - how to model a pause button?

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

I'm trying to get my brain around [Functional Reactive Programming](http://philipnilsson.github.io/badness), and specifically FRP with [Bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) and am having trouble finding the right combinator for creating a pause button.

```
var pauses = $('.pause').asEventStream('click');
var plays = $('.plays').asEventStream('click');
var ticks = Bacon.interval(500).whatGoesHere(???);
```

I want a pause signal to cut off the ticks signal and a play signal to reinstate it. Here's the marble chart that I want:

```
intervals   x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
pauses              x                         x     x
plays                         x       x               x
ticks       x x x x           x x x x x x x x         x x
```

It's ok if the timing is a bit off but this is the effect I want in general.

What combinator should I be using to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Merge plays and pauses as a property and filter the interval stream with it.

```
var pauses = $('.pause').asEventStream('click').map(false);
var plays = $('.plays').asEventStream('click').map(true);
var isTicking = pauses.merge(plays).toProperty(true);
var ticks = Bacon.interval(500).filter(isTicking);
```